# Jboss EAP 7 - Dynamic SSL authentication for REST API clients

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7

I'm trying to get my head around some questions about SSL certificates and their signing.

My need : I need to be able to add (generate?) client certificate to allow them to use my API.

My problem : It seems that Wildfly needs to be reload if the java truststore is changed in order for the modifications to be available.

What I understood : This is a wrong approach of the problem and what should be done is the following:

1. Get a CA certificate from a trusted authority
2. Add this certificate to my keystore
3. Use that certificate to sign the clients certificates

This way only my CA certificate needs to be on my java keystores and through the CA validation chain, my client would be allowed on my service.

Questions :

1. Did I got this right ?
2. If I'm supposed to sign my clients certificates, what are they supposed to send me for the signing to be possible ?
3. Can this be done without calling `keytool` utility ? I'd like as possible can be to use java to do this and not rely on the OS.
4. If my CA certificate comes from a trusted authority and I use it to sign my clients certificates, those this still count as self-signed certificate ?

Thanks for all the pointers that you could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Since it may help others I'm going to put what my various testing helped me to figured out. :

1. *Did I got this right ?*

As far as I can tell : Yes
Why can't I be sure about it ? Because I'm encountering some testing limitations due to my development environment and the fact that I can't have a real valid certificate with a valid domain to test it.

2. *If I'm supposed to sign my clients certificates, what are they supposed to send me for the signing to be possible ?*

So what they need to send for the signing to be possible is a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) and their public key.

3. *Can this be done without calling `keytool` utility ? I'd like as possible can be to use java to do this and not rely on the OS.*

This should be doable using the Bouncycastle library. I'm using *should* because I did not go into implementing it, more on tha later.

4. *If my CA certificate comes from a trusted authority and I use it to sign my clients certificates, those this still count as self-signed certificate ?*

I'm still not clear on that, but it seems that there is some kind of scope on certificate signing that prevents anyone from faking the actual CA. Anyone that can put more sure knowledge on this, is welcome.

**What I actually ended up doing :**

Being our own CA would be too much hurdle, so what we're actually going to do is ask our clients to get their certificates from known CA and add those CA certs to our truststore. This is the same principle as before but instead of us playing at being CA, we'll leverage actual CA sources.

Hope this helps anyone that would some kind of equivalent requirement.